# Map property entity to column(s) on parent entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's say I have two simple classes:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Price Price { get; set; }
}

public class Price
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set;
}
```

Notice how the product price is an instance of `Price`.

Now: I want to use Entity Framework (code first) to store instances of `Product` in a table named "Products", but I also would like it to simply store the Price property as a string, i.e. "100USD", or alternatively a decimal and string column.

By default, EF will also attempt to create a "Prices" table, but complains there's no usable property for the primary key.

Is there a way to work around this?

It is also important that I don't have to add "cruft" to my model, i.e. extra methods or properties to accommodate EF. Ideally, I would just have to configure EF to map instances of the 'Price' class to columns whenever it encounters it.

Comment: My advice: **don't do this!** - you can add the `Price` to the `Product` class - but ***please*** don't store a numerical value and a currency identification *in the same column!* Use two columns for those two pieces of information!

Comment: I see your point, and I agree: But the question is still valid, how do I get EF to map this tiny class to two columns on the "parent" entity rather than creating a new table?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure *exactly* the right notation, but this is pretty much the easiest and most maintainable way I know of.  (I've included marc_s's comment/advice below).

```
public class Product
{
  public Product()
  {
    this.Price = new Price();
  }

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }

  [NotMapped]
  public Price Price { get; set; }

  [Column("Price")]
  public string RawPrice 
  {
    get
    {
      return this.Price.<yourfield>;  
    }
    set
    {
      this.Price.SetRawValue(value);
    }
  }

  [Column("Currency")]
  public string RawCurrency
  {
    get
    {
      return this.Price.<yourfield>;  
    }
    set
    {
      this.Price.SetRawCurrency(value);
    }
  }
}

public class Price
{
  public decimal Amount { get; set; }
  public string Currency { get; set;
  public void SetRawPrice(string value)
  {
    //parse raw value into amount
  }
  public void SetRawCurrency(string value)
  {
    //parse raw value into currency
  }
}
```

This may or may not work, I cannot test it:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{ 
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

  modelBuilder.ComplexType<Price>();
  modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .Property(p => p.Price.Amount)
    .HasColumnName("Amount");
  modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .Property(p => p.Price.Currency)
    .HasColumnName("Currency");
}
```

I think this is suppose to flatten the model, but I've never done it before.  [YMMV](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/your+mileage+may+vary)!

Comment: I would like to avoid having to add code to my model just to accommodate EF: Other developers may be confused what the RawPrice property means and how it should be used.

Comment: You could always change the Raw properties to methods, but realize that using EF, a model is *always* a table (excluding inheritance building).

Comment: Ideally, I would be able to tell EF that whenever it encounters a property of type `Price` is should simply map it into column(s) on the parent entity. With your suggesting, I would have to add these methods or properties to all classes that has a `Price` property.

Comment: [Here is the fairly definitive list of things you can do with classes/properties in Entity Framework 6, and I don't see what you want on the list :(](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)

Comment: I made an update you can try, I won't be able to test until later today.